# Aumentar tamanho de campo varchar (existente no banco de dados) com NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Digamos que este campo com tamanho 11 existe no banco de dados, em vários clientes..

```
Map(x => x.CpfCnpj).Not.Nullable().Length(11);
```

E certo dia eu precise aumentar ele para .Length(14).
Existe alguma forma de configurar para que o NHibernate faça isto automaticamente, ou apenas via script no banco de dados?

Imagino que tenha  algo aqui para configurar, só nao encontrei ainda:

```
FluentConfiguration FConf = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(configDB)
                .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Map.UsuarioMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true));
```

Comment: eu acho que somente alterando direto no banco. De fato é a solução mais simples e rápida de atingir o que você quer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução viável, usar fluentmigration:

```
   public class PessoaMigration : Migration
   {
        public override void Down()
        {
        }

        public override void Up()
        {
            Alter.Column("cpfcnpj")
                .OnTable("Pessoa")
                .AsString(14);
        }
    }
```